# How to subtract a given amount of seconds in a given time period. Hour units can be negative

Tags: java, methods

i tried but it didn't work. Help me finish this method pls.

```
public class convert {
    private int hour, minute, second;

    public void prevSecond(int second){

        //Example1: 3:4:5 - 0:0:6 = 3:3:59
        //Example2: 0:0:0 - 0:0:125 = 0:-3:55

       this.second -= second;
        if(this.second < 0){
            this.minute -= Math.abs(this.second) / 60; 
            this.second = second % 60;
        }
        int temp = Math.abs(this.minute) / 60;
        if(this.minute < 0){
            this.minute = Math.abs(this.minute) % 60;
            this.hour -= temp;
        }            
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        convert a = new convert(3, 4, 5);
        a.prevSecond(6);
        System.out.println(a.toString()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you having problem with? You obviously started writing the code... you just need to finish it.

Comment: You could convert hour, minutes and seconds to total seconds minus given seconds, then convet back to hh:mm:ss

Comment: if i enter 125, it will return 0:2:5. But the result is 0:-3:55

Comment: Okay let me try @HimanshuAhire. Thanks

Comment: @zoNotStupid, one of this, Duration maybe, should help you if you do not have to implement your own https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html